# Android network bridge between USB tethering & WiFi hotspot interfaces

Tags: android, networking, iptables, tethering, hotspot

I have following hw environment:
- dev board;
- Android device;
- Ubuntu laptop;

Android connected to the board by USB cable.
Laptop connected to Android dev by wifi hotspot.

From Android I able to ping a board throw USB tethering (and vise versa).
Also from Android I able to ping a laptop throw wifi hotspot (vise versa).

|Dev board| <--- usb tether ---> |Android| <--- wifi ---> |laptop|

On Android device, I have usb0 and wlan0 interfaces.
I want to ping dev board from the laptop.

How to setup bridge? And this bridge should work with ADB throw wifi.

Android details:

## ifconfig

> bridge0   Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 58:A2:B5:7F:7B:21
>             inet6 addr: fe80::7824:93ff:fe96:c19f/64 Scope:Link
>             UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
>             RX packets:399 errors:0 dropped:21 overruns:0 frame:0
>             TX packets:358 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
>             collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
>             RX bytes:46412 (45.3 KiB)  TX bytes:26128 (25.5 KiB)
>
> lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
>             inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
>             inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
>             UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
>             RX packets:227 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
>             TX packets:227 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
>             collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
>             RX bytes:22816 (22.2 KiB)  TX bytes:22816 (22.2 KiB)
>
> usb0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr DE:46:31:73:06:7E
>             inet addr:192.168.42.129  Bcast:192.168.42.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
>             inet6 addr: fe80::dc46:31ff:fe73:67e/64 Scope:Link
>             UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
>             RX packets:449 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
>             TX packets:241 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
>             collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
>             RX bytes:33485 (32.7 KiB)  TX bytes:26750 (26.1 KiB)
>
> wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 58:A2:B5:7F:7B:21
>             inet addr:192.168.43.1  Bcast:192.168.43.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
>             inet6 addr: fe80::5aa2:b5ff:fe7f:7b21/64 Scope:Link
>             UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
>             RX packets:674 errors:0 dropped:3 overruns:0 frame:0
>             TX packets:398 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
>             collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
>             RX bytes:47625 (46.5 KiB)  TX bytes:35994 (35.1 KiB)

Interface bridge0 Android setup automatically when USB tether or wifi hotspot enabled.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I found solution for me.

Just

> echo "1" > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward

and remove all iptables rules

> iptables -F
>
> iptables -X
>
> iptables -t nat -F